# Change Color onClick in HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, background-color

I want to understand how this works. In the HTML is used the onclick="changeColor(**this**)" to communicate with the js. But if I change the word **this** in the HTML the code stops working. Why?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="script" href="script.js">
    <title>Tente você</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="changeColor(this)" style="background-color: blue;">
        Me aperte para mudar de cor!
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function changeColor(element) {
    var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    if (currentColor == "red") {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    
    else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a complex topic in JS. the answer of philale would satisfies but if you want to know more about this I suggest reading this article.

[gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 4):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?retiredLocale=de) is a **javascript keyword**, that **refers to the element** (the div) in this case. If you change it, the div won't be passed to the function, therefore you won't be able to access it and change the `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using `this` it is possible to pass in the `event` of the click, handy when more information should be passed to the function. Change in HTML: `onclick="changeColor(event)"`

```js
     function changeColor(event) {
        let element = event.currentTarget
        var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
        if (currentColor == "red") {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        
        else {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
     }
```

If you do not want to pass the event, it can be done like this in Javascript:

```js
     function changeColor() {
        let element = this.changeColor.caller.arguments[0].currentTarget        
        var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
        if (currentColor == "red") {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        
        else {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the element which is clicked. If you change that, you change what the element argument is in the function.

However, it's worth noting that the approach of using `onclick` inline event handlers is outdated and no longer good practice. The better approach is to use unobtrusive event handlers, contained in the JS logic directly:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
});

function changeColor(event) {
  const element = event.target;

  var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
  if (currentColor == "red") {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Me aperte para mudar de cor!
</div>
```